# How to store a application mobile state in memory?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am developing a mobile application, in C#, with the .NET Compact Framework 3.5. It needs to store the state in memory, i.e., if the application crashes, the application has to reboot into the state before the crash.

All business logic has to be stored too, as well as the forms. Is there an easy way to manage such a feature? Is serialization the right thing to do?

Comment: Won't crash the application again when you restore the *same* state? And if you mean 'an earlier clean state', shouldn't you be looking at a transactional database?

Comment: Good question ! In fact, the problem occurs mainly when the user shutdown manually the application (by taking away the battery for example). I think transactionnal database would be an overkill for this application.

Answer (score 1):

At first you shouldn't store the state in RAM, since it is lost after a crash. Instead you must use a non-volatile memory like a storage crash. Writing to this kind of medium is slow, so you must act accordingly.

I have seen some devices that had a recovery application, which can be configured to duplicate the whole content of RAM into flash every some period of time. After a hard reset it could bring the whole device to where it was (at least just before the last time RAM was duplicated).

Perhaps this kind of thing is an overkill for you. It could be simpler, as you've said, to serialize all your objects and periodically copy them to flash. It will be your responsibility what gets duplicated and what's not. It will be also your responsibility to initialize the application at its previous state.